# Using MongoDB to store immutable data?

Tags: mongodb, immutability

We investigation options to store and read a lot of immutable data (events) and I'd like some feedback on whether MongoDB would be a good fit.

Requirements:

1. We'll need to store about 10 events per seconds (but the rate will increase). Each event is small, about 1 Kb. Would it be fine to store all of these events in the same collection?
2. A really important requirement is that we need to be able to replay all events in order. I've read [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions) that MongoDB have a limit of 32 Mb when sorting documents using cursors. For us it would be fine to read all data in insertion order (like a table scan) so an explicit sort might not be necessary? Are cursors the way to go and would they be able to fullfil this requirement?

If MongoDB would be a good fit for this there some configuration or setting one can tune to increase performance or reliability for immutable data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to storing logs: lots of writes, and the data is read back in order. Luckily the Mongo Site has a recipe for this:

https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Regarding immutability of the data, that's not a problem for MongoDB.

Edit 2022-02-19:

Replacement link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150917095005/docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Snippet of content from page:

> This document outlines the basic patterns and principles for using
> MongoDB as a persistent storage engine for log data from servers and
> other machine data.
>
> Problem Servers generate a large number of events (i.e. logging,) that
> contain useful information about their operation including errors,
> warnings, and users behavior. By default, most servers, store these
> data in plain text log files on their local file systems.
>
> While plain-text logs are accessible and human-readable, they are
> difficult to use, reference, and analyze without holistic systems for
> aggregating and storing these data.
>
> Solution The solution described below assumes that each server
> generates events also consumes event data and that each server can
> access the MongoDB instance. Furthermore, this design assumes that the
> query rate for this logging data is substantially lower than common
> for logging applications with a high-bandwidth event stream.
>
> NOTE
>
> This case assumes that you’re using a standard uncapped collection for
> this event data, unless otherwise noted. See the section on capped
> collections
>
> Schema Design The schema for storing log data in MongoDB depends on
> the format of the event data that you’re storing. For a simple
> example, consider standard request logs in the combined format from
> the Apache HTTP Server. A line from these logs may resemble the
> following:

Comment: Your link is broken