# MongoDB for multitenant site configurations?

Tags: arrays, multi-tenant, configuration-files

On several occasions I've come across people using databases to store tenant configurations for multi-tenant platforms. I can hardly think of this having any advantages over storing configurations in static files with relevant ones getting loaded during start-up.

With relational databases, one could possibly claim that tables enforce some structure for the configuration, but with document-oriented databases, structure is not enforced.

Arguably, a similar (single-writer, potentially multiple-readers) scenario is [storing logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34829141/1827854), but in that situation there's the use case of searching through huge amounts of data and thus benefiting from non-linear search techniques. Configurations would hardly be so big to have such search performance issues.

In particular, could anyone suggest any solid reason why a configuration would be stored in MongoDB, rather than a simple plain-text file?

Comment: Probably the inherent JSON syntax validation on write could be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not convinced that this is a good solution, but in a way it is an "easy" solution to someone well acquainted with MongoDB. With time I've experienced some of the advantages. Here is what I can see being perceived as such:

- Comes "automatically distributed" in the sense that it being over the network the properties are accessible in a secure way to multiple web services.
- Depending on the client library and with lots of caveats, this commonly comes as "automatically reloading changes".
- Comes with "automatic" syntax validation (JSON in the case of MongoDB) - data cannot be saved if it is not syntactically valid.